# java application on nexus

Tags: java, nexus-one

Will java applications run on the nexus? I would want to run a particular java application.

Comment: Uh... If you mean, "I want to **write** a particular Java application", then your question belongs here. Otherwise, it should be asked somewhere else (and probably contain additional details regarding the nature of the application you wish to run), perhaps on SuperUser.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean the [Nexus One](http://www.google.com/phone). It uses [Android](http://www.android.com/) for operating system, for which applications are written in Java. But it uses a different virtual machine ([Dalvik](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_virtual_machine)) to run them. It will need at least a recompilation, but probably the user interface will not be compatible.

In short:

**Question:** Is it possible to take any Java application and run it unchanged on Android (Nexus) ?
**Answer:** *No*

Answer (score 0):

Applications on the android operating system are written in Java and compiled to run on the [dalvik](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_virtual_machine) virtual machine that runs on the android device. To run your specify program you will, at a minimum, need to recompile it.